# Importing json into excel using python + pandas

Tags: python, json, excel

I have a json file in the following format:

```
<Response>
<body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Container">
    <List>
        <date>2015-01-01T00:00:00+02:00</date>
        <price>20164.654</price>
    </List>
</body>
<resultCode>0</resultCode>
<resultDescription>success</resultDescription>
</Response>
```

What I need is the excel table with two columns in the  tag (price and date):

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╗
║    date      ║    price    ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2015-01-01   ║ 20164.654   ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

It seems pretty simple but I am not able to get the correct result. What I am getting is this:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║       ║           body           ║ resultCode║ ResultDescription║
╠═══════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ List  ║ {'price': 20164.654,     ║           ║                  ║
║       ║   'date':                ║           ║                  ║
║       ║  '2015-01-01T00:00:00.   ║           ║                  ║
║       ║    000+0200'},           ║ 0         ║ success          ║    
║       ║ { ...  etc.              ║           ║                  ║
╚═══════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I used this simple code:

```
pandas.read_json("url").to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

I tried using **json_normalize** but I keep getting errors.

Comment: That's a xml file not json

Comment: Result looks like that: `{"resultCode":"0","resultDescription":"success","body":{"List":[{"date":"2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+0200","price":20164.654},{"date":"2015-01-01T01:00:00.000+0200","price":18808.5089}]}}` Chrome displays it in the formal I pasted earlier